# Delete a file from OneDrive for Business in for each loop in Logic Apps gives an error

Tags: onedrive, azure-logic-apps

When I create a Logic App, I'm listing the file content in one drive for business. Then, I'm creating a `ForEach` to loop through the files in a folder and delete them. The system is not deleting the files and giving a 404 error.

I do the same example for copy, it works fine. The same example works fine if I replace the oneDrive for business adaptor with SFTP for example.

I've attached files for the design I've done and the error I get:

**LogicApp Workflow**
[image: LogicApp Workflow]

**404 Error**
[image: 404 Error]

Comment: Added "LogicApp Workflow" and "404 Error" images

Answer (score 1):

Delete file API by OneDrive takes an ID rather than the file path. So in your case, specify "Id" token and it should work.